# How to prevent direct HTML access in Angularjs 1.x?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

How to prevent direct HTML access in Angularjs 1.x?

**code:**

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
   url: "/",
   templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
   title: 'Home',
   controller: 'homeCtrl as home',
})
```

**In browser**

http://example.com/views/home.html in this case, my HTML file rendered in the browser

Comment: why do you need that?

Comment: Developers! ... flag instead vote down for new users let them improve the questions please, they need to help voting not help at all!

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: if you can improve the question you can either ask OP or do it yourself, closing is only when a post breaks site guidelines

Answer (score 1):

From a `.state`, you can only prevent the user from accessing your state by using [`resolve`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stateproviderstatestatename-stateconfig) and rejecting the promise

```
.state('home', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        title: 'Home',
        controller: 'homeCtrl as home',
        resolve: {
            isAutherized: function($q) {
                 // some logic goes here i guess...
                 return $q.reject("You shell not pass");
            }
        }
    })
```

This will fail transition, and by result will not access that specific HTML

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good solution https://solidfoundationwebdev.com/blog/posts/require-authentication-for-certain-routes-with-ui-router-in-angularjs

In general you should listen to $stateChangeStart event and check whether you got specific privileges to your destination or not and prevent it from change by for example making redirect.

```
angular.module("myApp").run(function ($rootScope, $state, AuthService) {
  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    if (toState.authenticate && !AuthService.isAuthenticated()){
      // User isn’t authenticated
      $state.transitionTo("login");
      event.preventDefault(); 
    }
  });
});
```